route issue integrate react theme in next js
i integrate route issue when i integrate MOfi react theme in next js, i face route/layout issue.
when i login and move to dashboard acording to my layouut condition when user is found render the sidebar and header, so when login is successfull they render the layoour but they donot change thhe route imidiately for first time after yarn dev, they take 10 sec to change the dashboard route menwile my sidebar,header and footer layour render because they found the user, durig this 10n sec ti chage the route login screen appear with sidebar,header and footer how can i solve them
i want when i login and response is true they imidiately change the route to dahoard so tthe login screen scree is not appear with sidebar,header and footer
